# How do I print the specific vendor bills reference numbers that are being paid in a check (NetSuite)?

Tags: html, netsuite

I am printing a check form in NetSuite. I would like the check printout to list all of the vendor bill reference numbers that are being paid as a part of this check. Is there a way to do that? I am using the below code to obtain the Vendor Payment related to the check, but I'm unable to retrieve the vendor bill reference numbers themselves.

Thank you.

```
<table style="position: absolute;overflow: hidden;left: 36pt;top: 15pt;width: 436pt;"><tr>
    <td>${check.tranid}</td>
    <td>${check.transactionNumber}</td>
    <td>${check.postingPeriod}</td>
    <td align="right">${check.amount}</td>
    </tr></table>
```

Comment: Is this for an Advanced PDF template? If so, you will need to bring the data into the record somehow, you might need to create an extra column field or something.

Comment: It's for an Advanced PDF template, yes. How would I do that? I'm not quite sure what syntax to use to find that data within NetSuite.

Comment: Try this {recordnaname.fieldid.secondaryfieldname} Example:{vendorbill.entity.companyname}

Comment: Did not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vendorpayment.apply` gives you the sequence of bills to which the vendor payment is applied. I have tested this by customizing the "Standard Check PDF/HTML Template" with the following code, which shows how to get the reference number, application date and amount.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
<body>
  <#list records as vendorpayment>
    <div>
      <#if vendorpayment.apply?has_content>
        <#list vendorpayment.apply as bill>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>${bill.applydate}</td>
              <td>${bill.refnum}</td>
              <td>${bill.amount}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </#list>
      </#if>
    </div>
  </#list>
</body>
</pdf>
```

Notes:

- `#if vendorpayment.apply?has_content` is required in case the payment is not applied to any bills (such as when previewing or saving; vendorpayment.apply then evaluates to `com.netledger.templates.model.StringModel`, which cannot be iterated over).
- The `div` is required so that the body has a child element if the `table` is not there because of the `#if`.

The documentation for the apply sublist of a VendorPayment is here: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/script/record/vendorpayment.html#field_apply_

Comment: Thank you for this. the .apply sublist does give you the bill details. Although I did run into a minor issue: it also prints any open bills related to the same vendor. I had to add a <#if apply.amount != 0> condition to get it to only print paid bills.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print information that is not on the Check record or linked via another field.  Global search "Page: Checks".  Select one of the records.  Are the Vendor Bill reference numbers on the record currently?  Or are the Vendor Bills linked to the Check record?  If not, you cannot print the information.  First get the information onto the record you're printing, then try to print it.

If the information is on the Check record, then where is it?  Is there a Vendor Bill list?  Is it under the Expenses & Items subtab?  How you print it will depend on how the information is shown/linked on the record.